# Ansible - Can a host access another host's host_vars file?

Tags: ansible

If I understand correctly, hostvars[] is used to access another host's facts, which have been retrieved by the gather_facts mechanism.

What I want is for one host to access another host's var file, located in host_vars/device.

For example, when running a playbook on host1, can host1 somehow access this file:

```
host_vars/host2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You should be able to access variables defined for another host (in host_vars). If you want to access a host2 variable for a task run on host1, you can do that as -

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars['host2']['my_var'] }}"
```

Contents of `./host_vars/host2`

```
$ cat host_vars/host2
my_var: "I am a host2 variable"
```

My inventory file -

```
$ cat ./hosts

[all]
host1 ansible_host=10.25.xx.yy
host2 ansible_host=10.25.xx.zz
```

Comment: I could have sworn that's exactly what I was doing yesterday "but it was not working".

Anyway, this works, it's great. Thank you.